# PuttyCyg not starting correctly: "Must be connected to a terminal" error message

Tags: windows-7, bash, cygwin, putty

My computer is running Windows 7 SP1 64 bits with CygWin 64 bits installed and updated (as for 16-Nov-2014).
I need to run the `screen` program of CygWin in a text console.

I am trying [PuttyCyg](https://code.google.com/p/puttycyg/), a supposed mod of Putty compiled to run without flaws CygWin's terminals:

[image: PuttyCyg]

But I don't know **how to start it** for my usual *bash shell*. What should I put in command line?

The best results until now is:

```
c:\CygWin\bin\bash.exe --login -i
```

But it yields me this result:

```
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell
```

and it seems no terminal is running (?) :

```
Luis@Windu ~
$ screen
screen
Must be connected to a terminal.
```

Maybe the image gives you some more detail:

[image: PuttyCyg just connected]

If I connect to `c:\CygWin\bin\bash.exe -i` I get:

```
bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device
bash: no job control in this shell

Luis@Windu /cygdrive/h/Temporal/Probando/puttycyg-20101029
$ screen
screen
bash: screen: command not found

Luis@Windu /cygdrive/h/Temporal/Probando/puttycyg-20101029
$ /bin/screen
/bin/screen
Must be connected to a terminal.

Luis@Windu /cygdrive/h/Temporal/Probando/puttycyg-20101029
$
```

I have tested with no luck (the window vanishes, or get stuck):

```
c:\CygWin\bin\bash.exe --login
c:\CygWin\bin\bash.exe
-
--
```

According to the [official docs](https://code.google.com/p/puttycyg/w/list) it should be as easy as typing `-`.

What is the appropriate way to start PuttyCyg?